# tensorflow max preserve mapping which is smooth

Tags: tensorflow, mapping, max

How can I make `x` from `y` where

```
x = tf.constant([[1,5,3], [100,20,3]])
y = ([[0,5,0], [100,0,0]])
```

So it basically preserves only the max values and makes other elements zero. Using `tf.argmax` we can get the max indices but don't really know how to make `y` from it.

Could you please help?

And would such `y` has its proper gradient (i.e., at the max element gradient 1 and at others gradient 0).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the optimized way but you can do it with `tf.gather_nd` and `tf.scatter_nd`. 1) use `tf.argmax` to construct the indices corresponding to the maximum values; 2) extract the maximum values using `tf.gather_nd` and indices; 3) make a new tensor with the indices and updates using `tf.scatter_nd`.

```
x = tf.constant([[1,5,3], [100,20,3]])
​
with tf.Session() as sess:
    indices = tf.stack([tf.range(x.shape[0], dtype=tf.int64), tf.argmax(x, axis=1)], axis=1)
    updates = tf.gather_nd(x, indices)
    output = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, x.shape)

    print(sess.run(output))

#[[  0   5   0]
# [100   0   0]]
```